# Issues with referencing Android library projects

Tags: android

I'm trying to use an ActionBar library project in my app but I keep getting errors when trying to add the library reference. I do it as described on the Android Developers website ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)) but it only copies the classes across to a folder called "actionbar_src". The error then comes when it tries to find the library's resources within the classes, which it didn't copy across. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What does it say the error is in the "Problems" tab?  Use the menu: Windows -> Show View -> Problems if it isn't currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Java Build Path -> Projects' did you also add the project there? I find I have to do both for the project to compile and run.